# Angular 2 - make component render using *ngFor along with other data types

Tags: html, angular

I have an array that I'm using to populate table cells. One of my array elements is the html for another component. My array is like:

```
row: ['prop1', this.transform(this.createMyComponent('prop2')), 'prop3']
```

this.transform() is a sanitizer, which uses DomSanitizer.

```
transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

this.createMyComponent() just returns the component, with possibly an updated property

```
createMyComponent(property) {
    return `<my-component [childProperty]="property"></my-component>`;
}
```

My html loop is

```
<td *ngFor="let column of row"><div [innerHtml]="column"></div></td>
```

I know that the component works well because it displays fine in its own `<td>` in this parent class. However, when I add it to the loop, as above, the html rendered is exactly what was returned from createMyComponent(). It does not render the component. How can I make this component render in this loop?

Comment: No, you can't do that with angular. The HTML needs to be compiled by the angular template compiler beforehand, and thus must be statically present in the HTML. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is that still valid in Angular 5? Sorry for commenting on old post, but it seems to be high on search results.